# Neural Network Project Ideas

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I am a Computing student with AI major. I am now researching topics for my final year project and I'm quite interested in Neural Network though I have almost no knowledge about it.

Topics I'm considering right now are language and music, so I'm looking for suggestion what will be interesting or popular scope what can be done with Neural Network for language and music. Feel free to give suggestion for different field, too.

Any input, suggestion, link, advice or pointer will be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Update: So I've narrowed the topic I'm most possibly doing to:

1. Music Genre Classification using NN
2. Text Mining Using NN

My question is whether both are too advanced to be done by undergraduate student?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have a look at https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php
and see if you find some topic that you like.

If you have experience with C++ and C it will be easier learning Matlab.

Regarding your topic to use, i suggest you see the link above, and try to find something that you like that can be applied to NN, search acm, ieee or other repositories for papers about NN and see if you can find also studies or reports about the topic you may be looking for.

Good luck.

Comment: Also when choosing a language think about what you are going to be doing after uni and what potential employers will want to see, for instance C# will probably win over VB.Net. I got my first graduate job largely based upon my final project and relied on what I had done during the project to illustrate my skills to potential employers.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I find it confusing (sorry, no offense), maybe it's too technical for me.

Comment: If you know a little about NN you should have no problems understanding that that link contain a lot of datasets, to be used on NN research, inside those datasets are reports and articles about the studies that were used on those topics. For instance you can find a dataset on poker hands and an article that explains how that dataset was used on using NN to predict future poker hands. This is just an example and there are a ton of datasets out there that can inspire you for a certain subject.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm beginning to see what you are talking about. Thanks!

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: link updated...

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I would be oversimplifying things, but I wish to disperse the mist a little bit. A simple neural network is a way to approximate a function, call it f, from (usually) R^n (real vector space of dimension n) to R^m and like. Suppose m=1. Instead of seeking a polynomial P(x_1,..,x_n) approximating your function based on a set of samples (p,f(p)), you seek to find the parameters a_i, b_ij in something like s(a_1*s(b_11*x_1+b_n1*x_n)+...+a_t*s(b_1t*x_1+b_nt*x_n)) where s is, for example, the "sigmoid" function, so that this strange function matches your samples well.

The motivation is supposedly biological. The "training algorithm" consists of successively adjusting the values of a_i, b_ij above so that the values of the resulting function at sample points p get closer "on the average" to f(p), via some variant of steepest descent, which, it is claimed, has good behaviour in some cases. NN were surrounded by a lot of hype in the 90-s, but considering its real objective which was to approximate an unknown function based on its samples (contrary to the hyped objective which was to "imitate the human brain" or something like this), many other approximation schemes were suggested for the same scope - for example SVM ("support vector machines"), which have a more appealing justification (often misleading as well, after you see the black magic of seeking the "right kernel" for the job in research articles).

The point is however, that as long as you choose the right "features" for the job (i.e. find a good way to translate your music samples into points in a 100-dimensional, say, 
vector space), so that points of genre X will lie "close" to other points of genre X, and the points of genre Y will lie "close" to the points of genre Y, and points of genre X will lie far apart from points of genre Y, you may use NN, SVM, decision trees or whatever else you like to separate the genres (the precision and efficiency may vary, though). The point is to find the right set of features - at least if we understand AI in this sense (but if this was the only sense, I think that IBM Watson would not be possible..)

Comment: it should be added, that one of the hottest recent themes in machine learning is "deep learning", viewed by some, according to wikipedia, as "rebranding of neural networks"; the point is however that there are new algorithms (and paradigms?) which address some of the drawbacks of the earlier neural networks algorithms, and which seem to work well in practice (so that in some cases they seem to be the state of the art http://www.quora.com/For-which-problems-are-deep-learning-algorithms-the-state-of-the-art)

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good Google Tech Talk about Neural networks.

[youtube.com/watch?v=AyzOUbkUf3M](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyzOUbkUf3M)

If you're serious about using a neural network for you culminating project it's well worth hour.

As for text vs music.  Neural networks are great classifiers.  They are fairly easy to teach with static data that has a true/false,on/off classification.  A little bit more challenging when the network needs to classify the input into sets.

Neural networks have the most trouble with streaming data.  There are some well known techniques to get this to work, but your intuition as to which will work well is not enough.  You'll need to look at what other scientists and done and duplicate their technique.  Otherwise you run a giant risk of creating a problem space NN are poorly suited to learn from.

I don't think you'll get interesting results streaming the music's wave form through a neural network.  You'll need to pre process the data into a usable format.

The last thing you'll need is LOTS of data.  The more the better.  You need the baked data and it's classification.  Hundreds of thousands.  You will not be able to classify some by hand to create a learning data set.

So considering all this Text classification is much more doable than music.

Neural neworks need a HUGE corpus of data.  Wikipedia is huge, and has lots of meta information about each page (popularity, quality, edit counts, etc ).  Google can also get a large set of data that has a particluar classification, say "happy dogs" vs "sad dogs", or just "dogs" where google's rank is it classification.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, Music Genre Classification would be too hard for an undergraduate project. The problem is that before you can get to the "fun stuff" of applying a neural net classifier, you'll need to do all kinds of signal-processing groundwork to produce meaningful feature vectors for the net. Consider beats per minute: it's reliable for certain types of music, but far from all. If you still want to go ahead, look at using something like libxtract as a base tool.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog
this is where I learned all about AI Algorithms pertaining to Neural Networks. This API is a very good way to learn what you need in order to understand whats going on. I have since created an API for myself that I use frequently when simulating Boid choices. Not really necessary but it works.